# command start-domain failed glassfish 4.1

Tags: glassfish, centos6, glassfish-4.1

I successfully installed glassfish 4.1 on my centos server via ssh but I am unable to start the server.
when I type `./asadmin start-domain` I got this error below.

```java
Waiting for domain1 to start ......Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 137.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@33903879 in service registry.
Nov 24, 2014 10:42:08 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Nov 24, 2014 10:42:08 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Nov 24, 2014 10:42:08 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.

Command start-domain failed.
```

Can anyone help with this one?

Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about centos. Oracle GlassFish Server is now commercially [dead](http://blog.arungupta.me/2013/11/glassfish-commercial-is-dead-wildfly-and-jboss-eap-to-rescue/). It is only available for reference and not meant for production (if you're trying to host something in the production). - it may or may not be the cause of the exception - I precisely do not know anymore.

Comment: @Tiny Oh I see. thanks for the info. can you transfer it to answer so that I can mark this question as solved. I will just change to another server. what can you recommend as server. I'll use jersey and jpa. Thank you.

Comment: Someone who is diplomatic (that I am certainly not) could have a better and more canonical answer - perhaps completely different from what I mentioned (which I think may be beneficial to you - should keep waiting for someone else to answer. I am generally currently question-oriented on this site except for answering to my own questions whenever necessary). To the server choice, I only listen to other people. Hence, it is not a milestone. WildFly or TomEE as open source application servers are usually recommended but that's fully dependent upon a choice & many more technical/commercial aspects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Glassfish cannot start because an address is trying to bind is already in use.

Shutting down server due to startup exception

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Try to edit the domain.xml.

> /glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml

The most common problem would be that the http-listener ports are reused by another application. Find the following lines:

```
name="http-listener-1" port="8080" name="http-listener-1" port="9090"
```

And replace them with something like:

```
name="http-listener-2" port="8181" name="http-listener-2" port="9191"
```

You can also read more about the domain.xml